# Creating and Instance of a type return null

Tags: c#

```
frm =(Form)Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CreateInstance("EditFrom");
return frm;
```

this returns null value. How to get value

Comment: Try `typeof(EditFrom)` instead of "EditFrom".

Comment: This questions is really overly broad. If you can improve it, please flag it for moderator attention.

Answer (score 5):

Try specifying the fully qualifying name of the class including the namespace where it resides:

```
var frm = (Form)Assembly
    .GetEntryAssembly()
    .CreateInstance("SomeNamespace.EditForm");
```

where `SomeNamespace` is the namespace in which the `EditForm` class is defined. Also make sure that you have correctly specified the class name.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a typo (EditForm instead of EditFrom)? Otherwise check the answer from Darin Dimitrov;

```
frm =(Form)Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().CreateInstance("EditForm"); 
return frm;
```

Comment: @Sankar: Yes, I looked in msdn and there is written that you have to specify the full type name. This means the namespace followed by the class name separated by a point, eg. YourProjectNamespace.EditForm. See Darins answer (+1) and check the class name (because of the probable typo), this should help...